# Set the maximum amount of children in a flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

```
.Cards {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    .Card {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        flex: 1 0 50%; // !
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get this flexbox to set a maximum of 2 children per row. Even with `flex: 1 0 50%`, I'm getting this:

[image: site]
[image]

Why is this happening? Even adding `width: 50px` doesn't work.

Comment: And you expect us to guess what you wrote in the html ? Please provide a minimum reproducive example or at least show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide you html code so I'll suppose it's ok. Now seeing what you wrote, you need to wrap your items (You did it) but also need to give your items a size. The size you wrote is in pixel and does not represent half of the screen, you might have done a typo. Here is the minimum css you need for what you want :

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > * {
  width: 50%;
}
```

And here is a component to illustrate :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>Hello</div>
      <div>world</div>
      <div>Here</div>
      <div>I</div>
      <div>Am</div>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the [the repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-b3d6ti?file=index.js).

Answer (score 0):

A trick in css:

```
width: calc(100%/2);
```

Put this inside **Card**:

```
.Cards{
  ...
  .Card{
    width: calc(100%/2);
    ...
  }
}
```

More on calc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()

New approach, which is also easy to read.

Comment: Doesn't that simply mean `width: 50%`?

Comment: If he asked for (he didn't) 7 items or 3 items? then? I thought this was more readable. That's why? @AreebKhan

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad The number of item does not change anything here. @areebKhan yes it means `50%` here but it's still a good thing to know ^^

Comment: @QuentinGrisel , lets say for 7, `100/7=14.28`, and `14.28*7=99.96`, **`0.04`** is not a significant value, still there is something missing, that's all I wanted to say..